# Explain the Working of this for loop technique. how it works step by step?

Tags: java, for-loop

How this for loop statement works? Can we only use it to print arrays?

```
for (Integer i : arrayToSort){
        System.out.println(i.intValue());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This is the for-each loop, you can use it like the normal for-loop. Only the syntax is different. Please look at the https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html